# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda)

Tags: python, command, installation, conda

I am using Windows 10 with python version 3.7 installed. Now I need to use the command `pip install conda` but it is showing an error. I searched for it but couldn't find a suitable answer. Please help.

```
C:\Users\ATech>pip install conda
Collecting conda
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/c533c3136427be62c38cc0e038cabf167bb54489c2ced2f6df903c456861/conda-4.3.16.tar.gz
Collecting pycosat>=0.6.1 (from conda)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/fd/e38d68774c0a345b0090d608a90f1fbf423970d812f7ec7aef9ac024e648/pycosat-0.6.3.zip
Collecting requests>=2.12.4 (from conda)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ruamel.yaml>=0.11.14 (from conda)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/84/bcd094e5e1c0bfdfc87e31ecb9505b8d46998a9ab3eefc6a7183be3db84d/ruamel.yaml-0.15.88-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Collecting menuinst (from conda)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)
```

Comment: Though it should be possible to do this you should note that using ```pip install conda``` or ```easy_install conda``` will not give you conda as a standalone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [PyPi conda project](https://pypi.org/project/conda/) it seems python 3.7 is not supported (check the bottom left of the page).The package only looks to support up to python 3.6.

#### Edit

Though I posted a comment to this effect on your post, in case you missed it you should note that using `pip install conda` or `easy_install conda` will not give you conda as a standalone application.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: The answer to that question partly depends on what you want to use conda for. Regardless, you've got a couple of obvious options. Your first option would be to downgrade your python version from 3.7 to 3.6 and then ```pip install conda``` as before. A second (probably more sensible option) is to install an [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) on your PC, which already comes with conda and many other things set up for you right out the box

Comment: @Ralph I am on python 3.6.x version but get the same error as the above user.